# why can $\mathbb{E}_{x}[M^{\lambda}_{\inf{\{m, T_0, T_a\}}}]$ be decomposed this way?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I'm having a hard time understanding a step of the following :

**Start** :

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion starting at 0 and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} .$ Define $M_{t}^{\lambda}=e^{\lambda B_{t}-\lambda^{2} t / 2} $
$
\text { and } T_{a}=\inf \left\{t \geq 0: B_{t}=a\right\}
$

(1) First, let us remark that for all $t \geq 0, M_{t}^{\lambda} \geq 0$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[M_{t}^{\lambda}\right]=e^{-\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}} \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda B_{t}}\right]=e^{-\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}} e^{\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}}=1
$$
Let $s \leq t$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[M_{t}^{\lambda} | \mathcal{F}_{s}\right] &=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda B_{t}-\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}} | \mathcal{F}_{s}\right] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda\left(B_{t}-B_{s}\right)-\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}} e^{\lambda B_{s}} | \mathcal{F}_{s}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
since $\left(B_{t}-B_{s}\right)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ and $B_{s}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ measurable
$$
=e^{\lambda B_{s}-\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}} \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda\left(B_{t}-B_{s}\right)}\right]
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
{=e^{\lambda B_{s}-\lambda^{2} \frac{t}{2}+\lambda^{2} \frac{t-s}{2}}} \\
{=e^{\lambda B_{s}-\lambda^{2} \frac{s}{2}}} \\
{=M_{s}^{\lambda}}
\end{array}
$$
Hence $M^{\lambda}$ is a martingale.

(2) Let $m \geq 0$ and let us denote $S_{m}=\inf \left\{T_{a}, T_{0}, m\right\} .$ Hence, $S_{m}$ is a stopping time since it is a minimum of stopping times. Furthermore, $S_{m}$ is bounded, and we have thanks to the optional stopping theorem,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{S_{m}}^{\lambda}\right]=\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{0}^{\lambda}\right]=e^{\lambda x}
$$
Furthermore, if $T_{0}=T_{a}=+\infty, 0 \leq B_{t} \leq a$ and for $\lambda>0, M_{S_{m}}^{\lambda}=$
$\exp \left(\lambda B_{m}-\lambda^{2} \frac{m}{2}\right) \leq \exp \left(\lambda a-\lambda^{2} \frac{m}{2}\right) \rightarrow_{m \rightarrow 0} 0$
When $T_{0}<+\infty$ and $T_{a}<+\infty,$ we have $M_{T_{0}}^{\lambda}=e^{-\lambda^{2} \frac{T_{0}}{2}} \leq 1$ and
$$
M_{T_{a}}^{\lambda}=e^{\lambda a-\lambda^{2} \frac{T_{a}}{2}} \leq e^{\lambda a}, \text { and } M_{T_{0}}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \lambda_{\rightarrow 0} 1 \text { and } M_{T_{a}}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \lambda \rightarrow 0 \quad 1, \text { hence }
$$
$M_{\mathrm{inf}\left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)}^{\lambda} \rightarrow_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} 1 .$ Hence we have
$$\color{red}{
\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{\mathrm{inf}\left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\sup \left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)<+\infty}\right]+\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{m}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\inf \left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)=+\infty}\right]=e^{\lambda x} }
$$

By the dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{m}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\inf \left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)=+\infty}\right] \rightarrow_{m \rightarrow \infty} 0
$$

**End.**

why is  $\mathbb{E}_{x}[M_{\inf{\{T_{0}, T_{a}\}}}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\sup{\{T_{0}, T_{a}\}}<+\infty}]+\mathbb{E}_{x}[M_{m}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\inf{\{T_{0}, T_{a}\}}= +\infty}] =\mathbb{E}_{x}[M^{\lambda}_{\inf{\{m, T_0, T_a\}}}]$ ?

Shouldn't it be 
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{\mathrm{inf}\left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\color{red}{\inf \left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)<+\infty}}\right]+\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[M_{m}^{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\inf \left(T_{0}, T_{a}\right)=+\infty}\right]=e^{\lambda x} $$

Comment: No? You want disjoint cases. If the inf is finite, one of them can be infinite. If the sup is finite on the other hand, both are finite.